# Adding space or margin around AG Grid Angular columns

Tags: css, typescript, ag-grid-angular

I am using AG Grid for Angular and community edition. I am trying to add space or marge around the left and right side of the cell but nothing seems to be working. Here is the css I have tried.

```
.editableCell {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border: 0.5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box!important; /* To maintain cell size including padding and border */
  margin: 5px!important;

}
```

Even After this, it looks like this.

[image]

Comment: Did you try adding 'padding'? I'd also recommend adding 'width: 100%' to ensure that the cell takes entire space.